# ASP.NET CalendarExtender works in IE/Firefox but has long load times in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, calendarextender

I am using the ajax calendarextender on an ASP.NET WebForms application.

Selecting the textbox linked with the calendarextender works fine in IE and Firefox, but in chrome there is a very long delay before the calendar displays.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

more information

The issue occurs when the page is navigated to from the server side (tried both server.transfer and response.redirect), but not when the page is navigated to directly from the menu.  Again, everything works with IE/FF, but not with chrome.

Comment: Is the same behavior reproduced on this page?: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Comment: I too have just noticed this issue today in the latest version of google chrome (26.0).  Is your color picker in a tabcontrol? I also only notice this in production, hosted on IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1):

I too noticed this issue today in the most recent version of google chrome (26.0).

I had searched the Chrome known issues for similar problems but nothing came up, pretty much your question is what I found... I had also noticed, that on the demo site, the colorpickerextender example works fine in chrome (26.0), but not on mine.

I ended up resolving this issue though, in both production / development environments.

My issue was that I had the colorpicker control within a tabcontrol, which that tabcontainer had `AutoPostBack="true"` .  Setting the autopostback to false on the tabcontainer was what I had to do to resolve this issue, although it required me to change my logic a bit and pre load the tabs.

Any chance your control is a child of a control with `AutoPostBack="true"`? Perhaps the child of an ajax control?

EDIT: I also navigate to the page containing the colorpicker via server side.